# Apache how to make a directory only accessible from local and also use autheticate with valid-user

Tags: apache-2.4, http-authentication

I try to do this with require local and require valid-user but look like the require local override the valid-user. make the local acess don't need to authenticate

```
AuthName "Authenticate"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/home/tmp/.htpassword"
Require local
Require valid-user
```

When I remove the require local the authenticate is working. but it allow access from outside.
So how to configure this so I can only allow local access with valid-user

Answer (score 3):

From Apache 2.4 you have the option to use the [`RequireAll`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireall) grouping Directive:

```
<Directory /some/path>
    AuthName "Authenticate"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile "/home/tmp/.htpassword"
    <RequireAll>
       Require valid-user
       Require ip 192.168.1       
    </RequireAll>               
</Directory>
```

Without that explicit `RequireAll` directive Apache uses an implicit [`RequireAny`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireany) where successfully matching only one of requirements is sufficient to be granted access.

In Apache 2.2 you had less granular control but could have used the [`Satisfy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#satisfy) directive to instruct Apache on how the Allow and Require directives should be combined.

```
<Directory /some/path>
    AuthName "Authenticate"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile "/home/tmp/.htpassword"
    Require valid-user
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 192.168.1       
    Satisfy All                
</Directory>
```

This requires both an authenticated user and the client IP-address from your local range: in this example`192.168.1.0/24`.

Comment: Hi, I'm have 2 configure. one is set at /etc/httpd/config/httpd.conf. with already set the require local. In this file it also set the directory can override all. But when I try to add RequireAll at .htaccess of the directory. It is not working. It access with not required to authenticate user. Then I try to comment out the Require local at httpd.conf and It work as expected. So how can I combine 2 files. with httpd.conf is unchanged and use .htaccess to override it. This is working on Apache 2.2.With Allow Directive. but not for Apache 2.4